# Solr Admin UI Error 500 #/Object Expected

Tags: solr

I need help here. Used Solr and process 2 commands: start and create a core. But when I try to access the Admin UI, It pops up this error

```
500 Error get #/Object Expected
```

and I cannot see the dashboard. The commands I used is just 2 simple steps:

```
bin\solr start
bin\solr create -c Test
```

The cmd shows that the core is created successfully. Does anyone knows why?
I using solr 5.1.0 and java version 1.7. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I got the same error using Internet Explorer 8, however, the error does not appear when using Chrome (version 45.0...) so my answer is, try using a different browser from IE.